# React and core-js can't polyfill for IE10

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, babeljs, polyfills

## Problem

For some reason my React app runs in document mode IE 10 as a standard when published to the company's DNS. Weird admin settings I have no control over.

Any way, support for IE 10 was needed. In IE 11 it worked fine, using the suggested [react-app-polyfills](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill):

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

And then, trying with `ie9` instead of `ie11`. No success, the app crashed. Did the polyfill not work? I had a lot of error messages such as:

```
Unhandled promise rejection Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
   "Unhandled promise rejection"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      description: "Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.",
      message: "Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.",
      name: "Error",
      stack: "Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
   at _o (https://the-company's-domain.com/static/js/2.517170ee.chunk.js:2:559477)
   at Anonymous function (https://the-company's-domain.com/static/js/2.517170ee.chunk.js:2:564365)
   at Ra (https://the-company's-domain.com/static/js/2.517170ee.chunk.js:2:573836)
   at gs (https://the-company's-domain.com/static/js/2.517170ee.chunk.js:2:614144)
   at cu (https://the-company's-domain.com/static/js/2.517170ee.chunk.js:2:604884)
   at su (https://the-company's-domain.com/static/js/2.517170ee.chunk.js:2:604812)
   at Zs (https://the-company's-domain.com/static/js/2.517170ee.chunk.js:2:601824)
   at Anonymous function (https://the-company's-domain.com/static/js/2.517170ee.chunk.js:2:553207)
   at t.unsta",
      Symbol()_a.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol()_m.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(extensions)_16.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(foo)_1a.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(foo)_17.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(foo)_18.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(foo)_19.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(meta)_2.ycgs6yczz8v: { },
      Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)_15.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(react.async_mode)_11.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(react.block)_10.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(react.concurrent_mode)_y.ycgs6yczziy: undefined,
      Symbol(react.context)_t.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(react.element)_n.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(react.forward_ref)_u.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(react.fragment)_p.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(react.fundamental)_12.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(react.lazy)_x.ycgs6yczziy: undefined,
      Symbol(react.memo)_w.ycgs6yczziy: undefined,
      Symbol(react.portal)_o.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(react.profiler)_r.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(react.provider)_s.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(react.responder)_13.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(react.scope)_14.ycgs6yczzi: undefined,
      Symbol(react.strict_mode)_q.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(react.suspense)_v.ycgs6yczz5z: undefined,
      Symbol(react.suspense_list)_z.ycgs6yczziy: undefined
   }
```

Very hard to understand the minified bundle, since I could only replicate this problem LIVE, not in dev (some dependencies in `create-react-app` doesn't work with polyfill + hot-reload). This link [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%7D&args[]=](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args%5B%5D=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%7D&args%5B%5D=) led to this:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Which made me believe it had something to do with an unsuccessful polyfill on `Object`....  (I was wrong, read answer below)

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

*8 hours later... (thank god I'm getting paid for this)*

Turns out, the polyfill on Object **added** an element to the object, which completely messed with my code when I iterated over it, like this...

```
Object.entries(queryData.data.time).map((day) => {
... did stuff
```

Weird stuff, no problem in IE11 or any other browser.

### Take away

Apparently some polyfills add a `__proto__` element to the object. Be aware!